# Question about chemical potential of a multicomponent ideal gas

Tags: mixtures, ideal-gas, chemical-potential

Consider a pure ideal gas, i.e. only having one component. The chemical potential and free energy of this gas are as follows:

$$\mu_1=\mu^\circ(T)+RT\ln\left(P\right)$$

$$G_1=n\mu_1$$

Where n is the total number of gas moles.

Now, just assume that we divide the molecules in gas by two, and treat each of these tow parts as a separate component. This is just an imaginary division, and none of P, T, composition, number of molecules are changed. So, we expect the free energy to remain the same as well.

Now, the chemical potential for each of these two component is identical and reads as

$$\mu_2=\mu^\circ(T)+RT\ln\left(P\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

and the free energy is

$$G_2=\mu_2\left(n\frac{1}{2}+n\frac{1}{2}\right)=n\mu_2$$

Now my question is that why is not G_1 equal to G_2?

Edit: To illustrate this I have envisaged two cases for making the gas divided in two parts, please see that attached image. In case 1, the gas is divided into to compartments with half of the volume of the initial compartment. In case 2, the gas is divided into to compartments with the same volume as the initial compartment.

I got two different Delta G values for these two cases. In the first case Delta G is zero and chemical potential does not change, but for case 2 chemical potential changes as described above.

[image]

Comment: Why did you write P/2 when pressure is supposed to remain same?

Comment: The partial pressure of each part will be p/2. See Eq. 12.24 here https://www.bcp.fu-berlin.de/en/chemie/chemie/forschung/PhysTheoChem/agkeller/_Docs/StatTD19/12_MixturesOfIdealGases.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your comment! No, there is no change in the gas, no dimerization or change in molecular interactions. 

It is just an imaginary division of the gas molecules to two identical parts.

Comment: @bloodybutunbowed0 are the volumes of our imaginary compartments equal or not?

Comment: @NatashaJ yes it is equal along with all other properties such as pressure and temperature.

Comment: @Poutnik I think it should be possible to do such separation. Consider that the gas free energy is the sum of chemical potentials of all its molecules, so it should be fine to assume that its free energy can be the sum of two imaginary parts assumed by us.

Comment: @Poutnik could you explain more? Why is wrong to assume that the gas is mixture of two separate molecules? I’m sure that I’m doing sth wrong, but cannot just find it.

Comment: To clarify, is the scenario like this? : Case 1: given p,T,V, nA of ideal gas A with mi0,A. Case 2: p,V, T as Case 1, but I. gases B and C with mi0,A=mi0,B=mi0, C, also nB = nC=nA / 2? // If yes, then calculate miB and miC before and after mixing them up at constant pressure, with the the difference of  G as the Gibbs energy change of mixing. Before mixing Case2 G = Case1 G. After mixing, it is lower.

Comment: But if you mean just formal dividing molecules of an ideal gas to two substances, while keeping the molecules intact, then your calculation  is off. It must be based on exchange of volume work, heat and entropy from standard to particular state. You need to formally derive contributions of the formal components to these parameters.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks a lot! Based on your points, I have considered two scenarios for separating the gas into two identical parts (I have edited the question, have a look please).

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of essential parts. 
// You may find useful formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).